# No Endpoint for WCF service in ASP.NET application

Tags: wcf, configuration, endpoint, service-reference

I have created and hosted a service `http://www.royalbatteriesws.somee.com/Default.svc`

I want to test my service for its functionality.

I have added a service reference in my Asp.Net web site called `RoyalBatteriesWS`

As no endpoint was added automatically in the `web.config` file, I had to add it manually.

`web.config` file:

`System.ServiceModel` and `ServiceBehaviors` sections:

```
<service name="RoyalBatteriesWS" behaviorConfiguration="HelloServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint 
        address ="http://www.royalbatteriesws.somee.com/Default.svc" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="RoyalBatteriesWS.IService">
    </endpoint>
</service>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HelloServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

I get an exception

> Could Not find default Endpoint that references contract 'RoyalBatteriesWS.Iservice' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Please can anybody point out my mistake?

I went through previous posts and I couldn't find what works for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `name="..."` attribute of your `<service>` must match **exactly** the **fully-qualified name** of the .NET class that implements that service.

This means: it has to be the exact **class name** and all namespaces of that class.

So most likely, your service class is called `RoyalBatteriesWS` - but there's a good chance it's stored in some namespace - so add that namespace to that attribute and you should be good to go!

On the other hand, since you said you added a *service reference* - do you really want to configure a **service** here - that's the **server-side** of things (where the actual service class is coded).

Don't you want to configure a class that consumes / uses that service - a **client** ??

If so - use the `<client>` tag (instead of `<service>`):

```
<client name="RoyalBatteriesWS">
    <endpoint 
        address ="http://www.royalbatteriesws.somee.com/Default.svc" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="RoyalBatteriesWS.IService">
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I was missing metadata binding in the webservice's config file.
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior" name="RoyalBatteriesWS.Default">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="RoyalBatteriesWS.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
             binding="mexHttpBinding"
             contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
After adding this in the WCF's config file,adding serviceRefernce on client app generates endpoint ON ITS OWN 
So my work is done:)